# JQuery caching pictures got by Ajax

Tags: ajax, caching, jquery

I got a page which asynchronously loads multiple pictures multiple times.

What I now do is that:

```
$('#map').append('<div id="'+(x.ID)+'"> <img id="pic" src ="'+x.src+'">  </div>');
```

How can I cache this pictures best? I got about 10 pictures, and everytime there is a server interaction for each image.

They are not very big, but all I tried wasn't very fast.

So how to cache?

UPDATE:

its not really about getting the complete image again, but Chrome seems to check everytime, wether the graphics have been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictures are cached automatically. Please check the **NET** tab on your **Firebug**.

Comment: did so, it shows up, that the client is checking wether the graphic has been modified. Is there a way to avoid that?(by caching options or somethin)?

Comment: What's the status of your images on NET tab? Is it `304` or `200`?

Comment: 304 - takes about 150ms to figure that out. lets say i got 100 pictures like that, and he does 100 times the "is it modified"-thing... it somewhen this will get awkward. Or do i think in the wrong way?

Comment: I guess you don't need to worry about that how rendering engine evaluating whether to read from cache or request the server. It should be OK with you unless your images are requested to the server again

Comment: Thank you. You brought me to this: [link](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/192918) which seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

The picture itself should automatically be cached unless you've specifically set the Ajax call to use `cache: false`

[update: ] I don't actually see an Ajax call being made. I assumed there was just some missing code but now I see what's up. The answer should still stand, though; as long as that href isn't dynamic, it should cache.

Comment: im not using cached: false, and the information that there is massive interaction with the server comes from google chrome network tab

Comment: Is your browser itself set to not cache resources (to help with development, when caching can sometimes be a pain)?

Comment: don't think so, it connects to the server checking if the graphic has been modified. is there a way to avoid that?